# Css borders fitting on left and right

Tags: css

if I want my footer to fit on the left and right side 
how it can be done ?  I don't want spaces neither on the left side nor on the right side. thank you !

```
#footer {
    background: url("../templates/images/17.jpg");
    background-size: 1300px 200px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    border: 0px solid #CCC;
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
}
```

Comment: Set your width to 100%.

Comment: and remove the margin and padding from the body

Comment: it doesn't work @jordan  oky wait

Comment: It's really hard to help with only this much.

Comment: didn;t work @jordan

Comment: Got it the first time you told me.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width of your element to 100% and margin and padding of body to 0.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: it worked on the left side ...what about the rigght side ?

Comment: your background size is fixed. could it be that your background is to small for your display? Try adding `background-color:red;` to see if the element is taking the whole space or not.

Comment: it worked on the right side ...so how can I fix it ?

Comment: just another question ..why wen I set  the position to fixed the footer disappears

Comment: try setting the width of the background size to 100%

Comment: it worked thanks a lot

Comment: maybe because the footer is behind your header (if you have one). when no relations are given, a fixed element defaults to the top of the page setting `bottom: 0px;` should bring it down

Comment: Do not forget to mark the question as answered :)